# Symfony2 Admingenerator vs. Sonata admin

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

Just found out about this new project [Symfony2 Admin Generator](https://github.com/symfony2admingenerator/AdmingeneratorGeneratorBundle). It is for easy development of backends for symfony2 based applications.

I was wondering, how this tool is different from [Sonata admin](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/index.html) project? Is there any use case where this new admin generator would be preferred?

Comment: I wouldn't try it, since it's really new. And imho it's silly to reinvent the wheel when you can just upgrade it.

Comment: well this is a useful question (12 thousand + views) but, like always, the mods with no common sense have closed it down. some rules on SO are really annoying

Answer (score 29):

> The two bundles are actively developed so those considerations can
>   change in the near future.

I've migrated my admin panels from symfony2admingenerator to SonataAdmin recently, partly due to some bug in symfony2admingenerator, and partly because I've found SonataAdmin clearer.

- SA uses an OOP approach, while S2AG rely on a yml config to define the admin panels
- S2AG need to generate a complete CRUD structure via command (controllers, views, and a yml config), while SA panels are only 1 DI Service Class
- in S2AG the configuration options are more obscure, since they are based on a yml file and on autogenerated classes, and often an error doesn't yield a meaningful message/stacktrace
- in S2AG is simplier to customize the rendering of a field.
- in the S2AG web pages, some parameters (like the filter of a list) are stored in the Session, rather than in the query string. This lead to the difficulty to link directly to a filtered list (eg: The comments by an user)
- SA seemed more stable, but the MongoDB part is less developed and has less features than the ORM part.